# Executing local shell script commands in pig

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, apache-pig

Is it possible to exexute a shell script command from my unix directory in pig file system?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can run a shell command from within your Pig script:

```
--declare a shell command
%declare command `shell_command`
file = LOAD 'file.txt' AS (colA:chararray, colB:int) ;

file_processed = FOREACH file GENERATE colA, colB, (command) AS colC ;
```

The result of the `shell_command` execution would be available in `command` which is later substituted in the `generate` step.

Comment: its $command when used in FOREACH (or anywhere in the script for that matter).